# Nesting Triangles using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to nest 4 equilateral triangles of size 20, 40, 60 and 8 with an equal spacing of 7 within turtle.

**Code**:

```
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 4

side = 3

for spacing in range(1, number_of_shapes+1):

    for sides in range(1, side+1):
       forward(20*spacing)
       left(360/side)

    penup()
    goto(-10*spacing, -7*spacing)
    pendown()
```

I had to use -10*spacing in the goto(-10*spacing, -7*spacing) to get a near equal spacing between nested equilateral triangles. I was wondering if there was a way to just use the number 7 to achieve equal spacing.

Comment: Please fix the indentation for your code.

Comment: connect corners  and you will see angel 30deg. it creates rectangular triangle with sides 10 and 7. Only 45deg create rectangular triangle with  with sides 7 and 7. But probalby using `cos(30)`, `sin(30)` or `tan(30)` and 7 you can calculate 10.

Answer (score 0):

Connect corners and you will see angel `30deg`. It creates rectangular triangle with sides `10` and `7`. Only `45deg` creates rectangular triangle with with sides `10` and `10`.

But values `(10, 7)` are not correct. Correct values are `(10, 5.8)` - but they may create spaces which don't look as good as for `(10, 7)` on monitors which use only integer values to display elements.

```
a = 10
b = 10 * tangens(30deg) = 5.8
```

I use these values to create space between triangels and next I draw line with angle 30 deg - it connects corners ideally. If you use `b = 7` then you get your triangles and this line will not connect cornerts

```
from turtle import *
import math

number_of_shapes = 4

side = 3

a = 10
b = math.tan(math.radians(30)) * a
# b = 7

for spacing in range(1,number_of_shapes +1):

    for sides in range(1,side+1):

       forward(20*spacing)

       left(360/side)

    penup()

    goto(-a * spacing, -b * spacing)

    pendown()


left(30)
forward(100)
```

`(10, 7)` gives:

[image]

`(10, 5.8)` gives:

[image]

`(10, 5.8)` puts triangles in correct places but monitors are not ideal (they can only use integer values for `x,y`) so spaces between triangles may not looks as good as in your version.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a classic "better living through stamping" problem.  Triangles are *drawn* from one corner but *stamped* from the center, which solves the centering problem:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('triangle', visible=False)
turtle.fillcolor('white')
turtle.right(30)  # lay bottom on horizontal

for sizing in range(NUMBER_OF_SHAPES, 0, -1):

    turtle.shapesize(20 * sizing / CURSOR_SIZE)

    turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

OP's drawn triangles on the left, the triangles stamped by the above code on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If OP read his assignment question properly, only the bottom side of the triangles need to have a spacing of 7 :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.